# Warning in Rmarkdown ( Warning in file(con, "r") : file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former)

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

would someone highlight what may be causing this warning in a flexdashboard with `runtime:shiny` set?

```
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
```

I'm suspecting it also affects the background color of the dashboard, which I cannot set to the colour I supply through the `bslib` package.